# SVN - How to merge a fix on a branch to all afterwards branches and trunk?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recently did a hotfix on release 1.0 of my project, it is an essential fix that all afterwards releases/branches like 1.1, 1.2, also the trunk need to be patched with it.

What should i do? btw, i am using tortoisesvn as the SVN client.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the fix to trunk, then merge it back to your 1.x branch. If you don't have an 1.x branch, create one from your 1.0 tag.
Such an y.x branch is usually used for exactly this: a stabilization branch from where the releases are tagged and where hotfixes can be applied to.